# Thread output not excecuting as expected

Tags: java, multithreading

This is my program.

```
class SimpleThread extends Thread {
    public SimpleThread(String str) {
        super(str);
    }
    public void run() {
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            System.out.println(i + " " + getName());
            try {
                sleep((int)(1000));
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {}
        }
        System.out.println("DONE! " + getName());
    }
}



  class TwoThreadsTest {
    public static void main (String[] args) {
        new SimpleThread("Jamaica").start();
        new SimpleThread("Fiji").start();
    }
}
```

I am getting output as

```
0 Jamaica
0 Fiji
1 Fiji
1 Jamaica
2 Jamaica
2 Fiji
3 Fiji
3 Jamaica
4 Fiji
4 Jamaica
5 Fiji
5 Jamaica
6 Fiji
6 Jamaica
7 Fiji
7 Jamaica
8 Jamaica
8 Fiji
9 Fiji
9 Jamaica
DONE! Fiji
DONE! Jamaica
```

my doubt..
1)thread jamaica is called first 
It is asked to sleep for 1000 milliseconds.
Then thread Fiji is called 
It should print and asked to go to sleep for 1000 millisecond.
but i am getting output as shown above.
Why is it not excecuting and printing thread jamica and fiji alternately

Comment: Read about thread priorities

Comment: There is no guaranteee that a thread will wake up after exactly 1000 ms it might take longer depending on whether system resources are available and how the scheduler is handling it.

Comment: `System.out.println()` takes different time every time you call it.

Comment: You need to offset them if you want them to alternate with just timer scheduling. As it is, they both run practically at the same time. Would be better to use a latch, though, if the exact order is really important.

Comment: I never understand these questions. If you want a specific execution order, why are you using threads?

Comment: @EJP this is a classic Threads exercise.

Answer (score 1):

The Console Output is not synchronized, therefore it may glitch like that in close-case scenarios. 
The threads are getting the command to print in the correct order, but the printing itself takes different times.

make the main thread sleep for 10 after starting Jamica and that'll put some distance between the two threads.

Code Example: (build upon OP's code):

```
class TwoThreadsTest extends Thread { // extends Thread addition
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SimpleThread a = new SimpleThread("A");
        SimpleThread b = new SimpleThread("B");
        a.start();
        try {
            sleep(10); // offsets Console Output de-synchronization
        } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
            // shouldn't happen
        }
        b.start();
    }
}

class SimpleThread extends Thread {
    public SimpleThread(String str) {
        super(str);
    }
    public void run() {
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            System.out.println(i + " " + getName());
            try {
                sleep((int)(1000)); // (int) is redundant
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {}
        }
        System.out.println("DONE! " + getName());
    }
}
```

Comment: Sleep in `main` will put distance between `0 Jamaica` and `0 Fiji`, but it doesn't guarantee the threads will print alternately.

Comment: @guy You are correct, yet the way to guarantee that the threads will print alternately will require either complex modification via wait\sleep, syncing the threads Or the use of Concurrent library. the problem here is the non-synchronized nature of the console output and not the code.

Comment: It's not the "nature of the console".  It's the application code.  Console output _is_ synchronized, which is why the output does not look like "1 Jam2 Fiaijica".  The application code is _not_ synchronized, which is why the winner is not predictable when the two threads race to call `System.out.println()`.

Comment: @jameslarge It is synchronized in the sense that two threads will receive an empty buffer when writing to System.out . but a call made to System.out.println() is not atomic and can be stopped mid-code. I believe that to be nature of the beast in this situation.

Comment: Stopped in mid-code? by what?  What does that mean?  `System.out` is a `java.io.PrintWriter` instance.  Oracle javadoc for that class says nothing about threads or synchronization, but the public methods in the OpenJDK implementation all synchronize on a private lock.  I'll wager that other implementations do the same.  The "nature of the beast" in this situation is that two threads continually race each other to call the synchronized `System.out.println` method, and sometimes one thread wins the race, and sometimes the other thread wins.

Comment: stopped in mid-code because its not atomic. a non atomic action can be stopped in mid-code than a new thread will take computing power, finish their println call and only after that will the first thread finish theirs.see [atomic actions][1]
  [1]: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/atomic.html for a much better explanation on atomic actions